# Search Display Controller tableview

Tags: uitableview, interface-builder, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a Search Bar and Search Display controller that I dragged from the Objects list on the right of Interface Builder. I placed this object on my DetailViewController's view. I set the delegate to be the DetailViewController. I have code in the DetailViewController to supply an NSArray of searched results to the tableview that shows up when text is typed in the search bar. Basically, the search bar is on top of the DetailView of a Master/Detail view....

Everything is working fine except how do I get access to the tableview so that I can graphically design the tableview and cells in the Interface Builder storyboard? I would like as much as possible to avoid designing views programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

The search display controller's table view doesn't exist until your app runs and the search takes place! So there's nothing to design until then. You can't set the search display controller's `searchResultsTableView`; you can only read it, so obviously you'll have to do that in code.

Comment: Thanks, I did end up designing the view programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back; I am often left wondering what people actually ended up doing...!